# How to load jndi bindings from within a Storm jar?

Tags: java, jndi, apache-storm, initial-context

We have a project moving to use Storm and as such our code must be packaged in a jar. We had previously used `com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory` as our `InitialContextFactory` implementation to load the `jndicontext` bindings from a file in the system config directory in the `classpath` (worked fine). However when attempting to use this factory to load the context from within the jar, we get the following:

```
javax.naming.InvalidNameException: unknown protocol: jar
     at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FScontextFactory.getFileNameFromURLSTring(FSContextFactory.java:139)
     at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory.createContext(RefFSContextFactory.java:31)
```

This is due to the factory attempting to load jdni context from the following URL:

"jar:file:/mount/storm-dir/data/storm.jar!/jndicontext"

This is a valid URL yet the factory does not understand how to open a jar. Is there an implementation of `javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory` that does? Alternatively is there a way I could work around this issue and add a config directory to Storm's `classpath`?